# Trouble with Java Homework

Tags: java

I am writing a program using 2 classes. My `TestState` class needs to access a variable from the second class, called `StateBirdAndFlower`.

The resource to read from the first class is an array called `stateData`, which corresponds to the second class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestState {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int position = getInfo(stateData, stateName); 
       //the error is here. stateData is not recogized.
     }
 }
```

And this is the second class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StateBirdAndFlower 
{
     String[][] stateData = new String[][] 
     {
        {"Alabama", "Yellowhammer", "Camelia"},
        {"Alaska", "Willow Ptarmigan", "Forget-Me-Not"},
        {"Arizona", "Cactus Wren", "Saguaro Cactus Blossom"},
        {"Arkansas", "Mockingbird", "Apple Blossom"},
        {"California", "California Valley Quail", "Golden Poppy"},
        {"Colorado", "Lark Bunting", "Rocky Mountain Columbine"},
        {"Connecticut", "Robin", "Mountain Laurel"},
        {"Delaware", "Blue Hen Chicken", "Peach Blossom"},
        {"Florida", "Mockingbird", "Orange Blossom"},
        {"Georgia", "Brown Thrasher", "Cherokee Rose"},
        {"Hawaii", "Nene", "Hawaiian Hibiscus"},
        {"Idaho", "Mountain Bluebird", "Syringa, mock orange"},
        {"Illinois", "Cardinal", "Violet"},
        {"Indiana", "Cardinal", "Peony"},
        {"Iowa", "Eastern Goldfinch", "Wild Praire Rose"},
        {"Kansas", "Western Meadowlark", "Sunflower"},
        {"Kentucky", "Cardinal", "Goldenrod"},           
        {"Louisiana", "Eastern Brown Pelican", "Magnolia"},
        {"Maine", "Chickadee", "Pine Cone and Tassel"},
        {"Maryland", "Baltimore Oriole", "Black-Eyed Susan"},
        {"Massachusetts", "Chickadee", "Mayflower"},
        {"Michigan", "Robin", "Apple Blossom"}
      };
}
```

My question is, how could I access this array from `TestState`, if is located on another class?

Comment: I don't see any reference to the StateBirdAndFlower class, which contains the stateData member variable, in your first code sample.

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but it is definitely an improvement. In your `TestState` class you call `getInfo(stateData, stateName);` but that class has no such method. I believe you meant to call `StateBirdAndFlower.getInfo(stateData, stateName);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this; Showing three for example:

**1. Static variable**

On your second class, modify the `stateData` variable and make it static:

```
 public class StateBirdAndFlower {
     //...
     public static String[][] stateData = (...)
     //...
 }
```

Now, from your first class, make a call to the static variable:

```
  int position = getInfo(StateBirdAndFlower.stateData, stateName);
```

**2. Getter method**

Create a getter method, which would involve instantiating the `StateBirdAndFlower` class on your code:

```
public class StateBirdAndFlower 
{
     //...
     public String[][] getStateData()
     {
        return stateData;
     }
     //...
 }
```

On your first class:

```
public class TestState 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      //...
      StateBirdAndFlower sbf = new StateBirdAndFlower();
      String[][] stateData = sbf.getStateData();
      //...
    }
 }
```

**3. Static Getter method**

You could also declare the `getStateData` method as static and avoid instatiating the `StateBirdAndFlower` class, by calling `StateBirdAndFlower.getStateData()` from your first class:

```
public class StateBirdAndFlower 
{
     //...
     public static String[][] getStateData()
     {
        return stateData;
     }
     //...
 }
```

And from the TestClass:

```
  int position = getInfo(StateBirdAndFlower.getStateData(), stateName);
```

Whichever method you use, try to call the method just once (save the `stateData` it into a local variable and avoid multiple calls to the other class' method, *even if the compiler optimizes this*)